# Actionscript 3 javascript communication: Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, externalinterface

I'm trying to call an Actionscript 3 method from Javascript but Chromes gives the error below:

> Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no
>   method

I put my SWF to the page as below:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="/subfolder/flash.swf" width="550" height="400" id="myFlash" name="myFlash" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" quality="high" />
```

Actionscript 3 Code:

```
function query(fn:String, ln:String):void {
    a_txt.text = fn + " " + ln;
}
ExternalInterface.addCallback("queryFlash", query);
```

And finally Javascript:

```
function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
      var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
      return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
    }
$(document).ready(function() {
    getFlashMovie("myFlash").queryFlash("a", "b");
});
```

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `ready()` corresponds to the `DOMContentLoaded` event. That means that the HTML page finished loading and you can access the DOM - but it doesn't guarantee you that all the embedded images and objects finished loading. So your Flash probably simply didn't load yet. You should listen to the window's `load` event instead.

Comment: Will the load event fire after the flash call back function is ready?

Comment: @The_asMan: It will fire after the Flash object finished loading - supposedly it is ready by then. If it isn't you might have found a Flash bug.

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty the load will fire only after all html objects (images,swfs,whatnot) are loaded. This does not ensure that the flash is completed and initialized. The only true method I have found is to add a javascript global var isFlashObjReady and have the flash call a javascript function to set the var to true.

Comment: Remember we have 2 processes running here the browser and flash plugin/activeX there is a detachment here that depending on the flash app might have to be dealt with.

Comment: one other thing he could try is wrap getFlashMovie("myFlash").queryFlash("a", "b");
in a try catch and keep calling on exception

Answer (score 0):

Even though it might not fix your problem, I had a similiar problem with Chrome.

The fix was to replace

```
document.getElementById('flash').sendToActionscript('test');
```

with

```
((function(){return document.getElementById('flash');})()).sendToActionscript('test');
```

If the id attribute of the embed/object was `flash` and the function to call inside flash was `sendToActionScript`

I have no idea why this works.

### Edit

This doesn't seem to always work. I found that creating the object using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) seems to always work for me.

Comment: Firstly, thank you. I know I've already marked Wladimir Palant's answer as correct one, but strangely I've started to experience this problem again. I will definetely try what you've suggested here.